# How to backup HornetQ

Tags: backup

We are running HornetQ on Amazon EC2. Now my question is how to backup the filesystem of HornetQ?

At the moment the current release of HornetQ states that only shared storage is supported and no direct replication. This leads to the fact that I need to be able to backup the filesystem where HornetQ puts its messages. How can I do that without affecting the current running application? Is there some copy command available or should I take snapshots of the device where the data runs on?

As it is a queue and it shouldn't grow very fast, would an option be to make a dedicated volume and then take snapshots of it?